# IIS Express how to enable detailed Error pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, .net-5, asp.net5

I'm at my wits end I keep getting a blank page when I try to register on my website at my "production" server.

**Note:** this issue is not on my development environment.

so I need somehow to enable the error page so I can get a clue on to what is wrong. ?
however when I try to enable

```
  <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
```

in the web.config I get a blank error page instead of the 500 error page that I normally got.
I've even changed the code to do the following to try and get a detailed error page:

```
   //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        //}
       // else
       // {
       //     app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
       //     app.UseHsts();
      //  }
```

I think it is something to do with my database and or some sort of permissions but I have no idea where to begin without knowing the detailed error message.

**EDIT 1:** I can run other pages just fine it is only the Registration page and I think also the login page. I'm using the Identity UI as a library. so I'm not in control of how that part is working. I feel the issue might be Database connection related but as I'm not having any error messages I'm not able to find out what is wrong..

**Edit 2:**
My connection string is like this and is connecting to a sqlexpress db on the localhost of the testserver.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhostName\\InstanceName;Database=DBname;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Comment: "at my "production" server", but then why the title says "IIS Express"?

Comment: @LexLi because my "production" server is serving the role of a production server in this setup but is in reality just a server temporary sat up for approximate the real life development process from a development to a production server... simply a way to experience an approximation of and get better at the deployment part of the development life cycle.